Creation and when satan fell
'In the begining God created the heavens and the earth, now the earth was formless'(Gen 1:1). The Hebrew text does not say 'now' but the earth 'she became' formless, the same word used when Lot's wife 'became' a pillar of salt. This is when satan was banished to the earth for his pride. Which is why only the light was good on day one and nothing was good on day two until the earth came out of the water on day three. All God could see on day two, in the water, was satan and his fallen followers. Since God chose to take 6 days to perfect the  planet for mankind why did He choose the same planet? Does this mean we have more to do than just worship God?

What's the question?

The above is simply stating, without fully substantiating the Hebrew vocabulary, what is held by many, namely that the state of creation, as such, was an indication of what would later be apparent within it - a conspiracy involving created spirit, woman and man. But the Stack Exchange model (which SE-C follows) involves asking a non-duplicated, clear, precise, substantiated question so that answers will provide an archive of information for researchers to access. Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

The [tour], the [help], [ask] and [answer] provide guidance on how to get the most out of this site. Please take a look and edit your question to make it more clear. Welcome.
